# Copy/Paste Special as Microsoft Graphic Object from Excel to Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a report I create each week that copies a series of charts into a series of slides. Currently, I have VBA code that copies and pastes the charts as images, but the client has asked that the charts be graphic objects so they can inspect the source data from the PPT. Below is a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
Sub CreatePPT

Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
 

Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
Set PPPres = SCPP.Presentations.Open("C:\filepath\Template.pptx")
PP.Visible = True

'Select the slide I want to paste the chart to (I am not really sure why I need this line, but get an error if I do not have it)
PPPres.Slides(1).Select
'Copy the range where the chart is located
Sheets("Charts").Range("c10:D20").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
'Paste the chart to the slide
PPPres.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste.Select


Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PP = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have tried using paste special, but none of the available data types is anything like the "Paste as Graphic Object" that is available when I manually copy/paste special from excel to ppt manually. Does anyone know it is possible to replicate this type of paste special using VBA? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried a regular Copy in Excel, and a regular paste in Ppt?

Comment: First, find out what the client means by Graphic Object.  Or at least find out how they'd create this thing manually so you know what they're after.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I have done it myself manually -- the process is to copy the chart in excel, then paste special and select "Microsoft Office Graphic Object" in ppt

Comment: OK ... from here, it looks like PasteSpecial and adding the parm for default paste OR just Paste.Special with no parm OR just Paste (nothing special, no chaser) all do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying a range (presumably under a chart) as a picture, copy the chart itself, regular copy, not copy picture. Then do a straightforward paste:

```
Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
PPPres.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
```

But if you don't send along the Excel source workbook, and if they don't set up the links properly, they won't be able to view the data in Excel.